# In EF Core with SQL Server, does a DbSet<MyClass> variable store the entire table in memory, or just the reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I do something like this:

```
var myTableRef = myDBContext.MyTable;
//Do something with myTableRef
```

Will the variable `myTableRef` store the the table's data in memory (which is not what I want)?  Or will it only hold a *reference* to the table?

Answer (score 3):

`myTableRef` will just be a reference to `myDBContext.MyTable`, i.e. a variable of type `DbSet<MyClass>`. It will not magically pull in all table data.

It would if you'd do `var myTableContents = myDBContext.MyTable.ToList()`.